# Default ofstream class argument in function

Tags: c++, arguments

I've got function. If user didn't provide `ofstream` element into this function:

```
bool isPolpierwsza(int, bool = false, ofstream = NULL);
```

than I want to asign "plik"

```
bool isPolpierwsza(int liczba, bool wypisz, ofstream plik)
```

to `NULL` value.

My compiler put error:

> 2.9.cpp:5:48: error: no viable conversion from 'long' to 'ofstream' (aka 'basic_ofstream')
>   `bool isPolpierwsza(int, bool = false, ofstream = NULL);`

How to setup default value to ofstream to be treated like `NULL` or "false"?

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: Overload it with a different function. It is C++, after all. so provide two versions; one without the stream (which should be a reference in the first place).

Comment: `ofstream` is not a pointer. You can't set it to `NULL`. The `NULL` macro is most probably defined as `0L`, hence this error.

Comment: There is no such thing as "a null value" generally. Some types (e.g. pointers or optional types) have such a notion, but most types don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two overloads, one of which *doesn't* take the `std::ofstream` argument:

```
bool isPolpierwsza(int liczba, bool wypisz)
{
    return isPolpierwsza(liczba, wypisz, /* your own argument */);
}
```

Comment: What would you use for `your own argument`, in the cases where the intention is not writing anything whenever `wypisz=false`?
Something "analogous" to `NULL` seems like the right thing...

Comment: Yes, you would simply pass `NULL` as the third argument

Comment: But I think `NULL` cannot be used for an `ofstream`.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio Change the `ofstream` argument to a pointer. (`ofstream*`).

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio And you check if the `ofstream` is valid with an if statement: `if (wypisz) { ... }`. And you dereference it like (`*stream`) in order to use it.

Comment: I guess this part is essential fo the propsal to work. I would add it to the answer.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63762945/default-null-value-for-an-ofstream

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the stream buffer instead:

```
bool isPolpierwsza(int, bool = false, std::streambuf* osbuf = nullptr)
{
    std::ostream os(osbuf? osbuf : std::cout.rdbuf());
    os << "yay it works\n";
    return false;
}
```

Now, call it like this:

```
std::ofstream ofs("myoutput.txt");
bool result = isPolpierwsza(42, true, ofs.rdbuf());
```

Or indeed, without the parameter.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Well, this feels more like in the spirit of the IOStream library design (which I know, hurts many people's eyes)

Answer (score -2):

First of all, it may be useful to use ostream instead of ofstream, as this is more general and considered better practice.

Then, you can simply assign 'cout' instead of 'NULL'. NULL doesn't work because ostream is not a pointer but a struct. This means the struct has to be filled out completely and can not be assigned NULL. Instead, you could use cout, like

```
bool isPolpierwsza(int, bool = false, ostream& = cout);
```

Comment: This won't even compile. streams cannot be publicly copied by-value. That last parameter needs to be a reference.

Comment: This will print stuff to standard output; I guess OP wanted not to print stuff at all!