# Default "NULL" value for an ofstream

Tags: c++, null, ofstream

I have currently a function

```
int myfun(const int a) {
    ...
    return rval;
}
```

that performs several actions.

I mean to adapt it to write debug information on its behaviour or not according to some parameter that I can pass.
In the cases I want to write that info, I also want to pass the `ofstream` to use.
And I want applications that were using `myfun` to still work with no modifications.

So I would ideally change to

```
int myfun(const int a, ofstream & ofs) {
    ...
    if (!(ofs == NULL)) {
        ofs << ...
    }
    ...
    if (!(ofs == NULL)) {
        ofs << ...
    }
    return rval;
}
```

with a default value similar to `&ofs=NULL`. I know `NULL` is not appropriate.

**What is an appropriate way of handling this?**

**Note 1**:
I could pass an optional parameter with the output file name, but that is less flexible.

**Note 2**:
I could also change to

```
int myfun(const int a, const bool debug_info, ofstream & ofs) {
    ...
    if (debug_info) {
        ofs << ...
    }
```

with a default value `debug_info=false`.
I guess this still requires a default value for `ofs` as above.

**Note 3**:
The accepted answer in [Default ofstream class argument in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469462/default-ofstream-class-argument-in-function) proposes an overload without the `ofs` parameter.
In my case that may not work, as I mean to not write anything when "`ofs=NULL`".

**Note 4**:
[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19470012/2707864) apparently works, but it seems somewhat contrived to me, and I am not sure it provides all the same functionality as with passing an `ofs`.

**Related**:

[Is there a null std::ostream implementation in C++ or libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243743/is-there-a-null-stdostream-implementation-in-c-or-libraries/8244321)

Comment: Make an abstract Logger class. In one implementation you can write to an ofs, and in the other do something else. Pass in the logger by reference into myfun().

Comment: @schteppe - Would this require replicating `myfun`?
I mean to modify `myfun`, and doing it at two separate places should be avoided.

Comment: no, the implementation would stay the same for myfun. I’ve posted pseudocode in an answer now.

Comment: You could use a *no-op ostream*, which is very easy to implement. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826554/standard-no-op-output-stream/11826787

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want applications that were using myfun to still work with no modifications.

If so, use an ofs with default `nullptr`

```
int myfun(const int a, ofstream *ofs = nullptr)
{
    if (ofs != nullptr)
    {
        // (*ofs) << ... ;
    }

    // ...
}
```

You can't use a reference parameter `ofstream& ofs` for such function because a reference cannot be null.

Comment: Simple solution!
Detail: within `myfun` one should use `(*ofs)` instead, e.g., `(*ofs) << ...;`.

Comment: that was commented code, but surely it should be `(*ofs)`. Btw, you can also remove the `nullptr` comparison as well by just `if(!ofs)`

Comment: This is what I ended up using.

Answer (score 2):

Make an abstract Logger class. It has a method for logging a message. In derived classes you can add logging to file (ofstream) or simply do nothing. You can use any logger, the implementation of myfun() stays the same.

```
#include <fstream>

class Logger {
public:
    virtual void log(const char*) = 0;
};

class NullLogger: public Logger {
public:
    void log(const char*) override {};
};

class FileLogger: public Logger {
public:
    FileLogger(std::ofstream& s): ofs(s){}
    void log(const char* msg) override {
        ofs << msg;
    }
private:
    std::ofstream& ofs;
};

static NullLogger defaultLogger;
int myfun(const int a, Logger& logger=defaultLogger)
{
    logger.log("hello");
    // ...
    logger.log("asdf");
}

int main(){
    std::ofstream ofs;
    FileLogger fileLogger(ofs);
    NullLogger nullLogger;
    myfun(10,fileLogger); // logs to file
    myfun(10,nullLogger); // logs nothing
    myfun(10); // also logs nothing
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good. You should add the default value for `logger`.
As stated in the OP, 
I want applications that were using `myfun` to still work with no modifications.
So `myfun(10)` should still work.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio I have to do some research to make sure that works first. Passing a mutable reference as default parameter seems to be a little bit problematic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816293/passing-optional-parameter-by-reference-in-c?lq=1

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio myfun(10) now works. See updated code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In C++17 there is a solution involving `std::optional` but since it requires default constructible types, `std::reference_wrapper` has to be used too.

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <optional>
#include <functional>

int myfun(const int a, std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<std::ofstream>> ofs)
{
    if (ofs) {
        ofs->get() << "...";
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::ofstream file;
    //Calling is quite nice.
    std::cout<<myfun(10,{file})<<'\n'; //Prints 1
    std::cout<<myfun(10,{})<<'\n'; //Prints 0
}
```

The downside of this solution, although idiomatic, is being verbose and heavy on the syntax in some cases.

Comment: As stated in the OP, 
I want applications that were using `myfun` to still work with no modifications.
So `myfun(10)` should still work.